# How to grow progress bar horizontally in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have an application where I have  a table and `ProgressBar`. I want to expand my progress bar when user resizes the window. For `TextBox` in JavaFX I can able to set `HBox` priority and achieve it as intended. But for `ProgressBar` it is not working.

Can any one tell me where I am doing wrong ?

```
HBox root = new HBox();           
final ProgressBar browser = new ProgressBar();

//  final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
// browser.setText("JJJ");
HBox.setHgrow(browser, Priority.ALWAYS);         
//  webEngine.loadContent("<b>asdf</b>");              
root.getChildren().add(browser);
scene.setRoot(root);
```

Comment: Show us your code and have you used any layout managers?

Comment: @JJPA Please check the code..

Comment: @JJPA I came across blog while searching for it http://amyfowlersblog.wordpress.com/2010/05/26/javafx-1-3-growing-shrinking-and-filling/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bind the widths of progress bar and Vbox:

```
VBox root = new VBox();
root.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
final ProgressBar browser = new ProgressBar();
browser.prefWidthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty().subtract(20));  //  -20 is for 
   // padding from right and left, since we aligned it to TOP_CENTER.
root.getChildren().add(browser);
```

Answer (score 15):

The best way is to set the maximum width of the progress bar.

`browser.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);`

and of course to tell the VBox to fill its children up to the full width (which is the default, so maybe not worth mentioning).

```
vbox.setFillWidth(true);
```

The answer given by Uluk might work in simple examples. However, it might lead to an uncontrolled growth of the parent, if the parent in response to a child changing its width decides to change its own width as well. Even in not overly complex layout such behavior can readily be observed.

Comment: This is the correct answer IMO.  Certain nodes have a default max width, `ProgressBar` included.  Overriding this will allow standard layout operations (e.g. `setFillWidth`) to behave "normally".